# I have a table view cell and I call a function from view controller and the function are in table view cell as shown in fig but it shows error

Tags: ios, swift

[image: View Controller 1]

[image: View Controller 2]

[image: Code Sample]

I have a table view cell and I call a function from `ViewController` and the function are in table view cell as shown in fig but it shows error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code as text, not images.

Comment: You are creating a new cell instance rather than setting the dictionary on the cell instance you just dequeued. Also, don't pass a dictionary. Create a struct to store your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a cell with the default initializer `()` returns a generic cell without connected IBOutlets hence the crash.

It’s pointless anyway. Just one line *ago* you dequeued a valid `cell`, use that.